# iOS : how to shrink a UIView.layer.shadow to a desired width?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have been adding a bottom shadow to a `UIButton` this way:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.33
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 6.0)
    }
}
```

The result I'm getting:

[image]

This works fine but I would like now to shrink the shadow width in order to have this rendering instead (picture from Sketch) :

[image]

Any idea of how to handle this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use layer's shadowPath property. add below code to **layoutSubviews** method and try.

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 0), cornerRadius: 4.0)
self.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I had the intuition of using `shadowPath` but did not know how to use it.

Comment: @Someday happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not find a more suitable answer, then try this:
Add a UIView under the button with the desired size and it is for her to make a shadow.